# Can any one help in casting below linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Here is my linq to sql query which is working fine but when i cast and return the data I get casting error.

```
var productImages = from prod in context.seller_productinventory.AsEnumerable()
                                    join prodImage in context.seller_productimages on prod.prdid equals prodImage.prdid
                                    join category in context.mstr_scategory on prod.mcid equals category.CategoryID
                                    join subcategory in context.mstr_scategory on prod.scid equals subcategory.CategoryID
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ProductId = prod.prdid,
                                        Category = category.CategoryName,
                                        Subcategory = subcategory.CategoryName,
                                        Image1 = prodImage.image1Path,
                                        Image2 = prodImage.image2Path,
                                        Image3 = prodImage.image3Path,
                                        Image4 = prodImage.image4Path,
                                        ProductStatusCd = (Convert.ToInt32(prod.isAdminApproved) != 1) ? "Pending Approval" : "Approved"
                                    };
```

I get error in below code.

```
return (IEnumerable<ProductImageModel>) productImages.ToList();
```

My Model Class:

```
public class ProductImageModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Subcategory { get; set; }
        public string Image1 { get; set; }
        public string Image2 { get; set; }
        public string Image3 { get; set; }
        public string Image4 { get; set; }
        public string ProductStatusCd { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: That's because you are selecting an `anonymous` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting an anonymous object using `select new` and later you are trying to cast a collection of anonymous objects to `IEnumerable<ProductImageModel>`, that will fail.

You have two options to fix that.

If your class `ProductImageModel` is not generated through entity framework then you can use that in your select statement like:

```
select new ProductImageModel
{
 //.... fields
}
```

Or the other option is to create a temporary template class, and project your fields to that class object.

**Remember,** If `ProductImageModel` is framework generated then you can't use that in column projection using `select`.

From your code, it seems that your class `ProductImageModel` is actually representing a table from database. You will be needing another class (DTO) with fields specified in `select` clause.

```
public class ProductImageModelDTO
{
  //your fields
}
```

and then in your LINQ query:

```
select new ProductImageModelDTO
  {
        ProductId = prod.prdid,
        //rest of the fields.
```

Your method return type in that case should be:

```
IEnumerable<ProductImageModelDTO>
```

Comment: Very well explained +1.

Comment: @SanjuRao, you are welcome. I believe if it has worked so quickly it must have been option 1, so your class `ProductImageModel` isn't generated through the framework.

Comment: Yes @Habib you are absolute right that class **ProductImageModel** is written by me and not generated from .edmx class.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `select new { ... }`, you're creating anonymous objects. Essentially, you end up with `IQueryable<object>` and that is contravariant with `IEnumerable<ProductImageModel>` (i.e., the compiler cannot cast from one to the other). The easiest solution is to select actual `ProductImageModel`s if that's what you're going to use:

```
select new ProductImageModel
{
    ...
}
```

Then, no casting is necessary.

Comment: I understand this issue entirely but what seems to feel like bad practice is you end up with say an entity framework / linq2sql object / class like Product.  You cant really use it in this case so you have to create another say Product class that isn't tied to entity framework or linq2sql that you can actually map to.  Is this quite normal for everyone else?  So you end up with two classes one specific to the db model and another as an Abstract Data Type have you that you can make the db model object to. +1 anyhow.

Comment: @JonH: It's not that you *can't* use the entity; it just very rarely makes sense to. Creating another class and mapping the entity data over to it gives you the freedom and ability to customize that class for specific purposes. The typical use case is for view models, which are classes customized to work with a specific view or set of views. Having these view models, then allows you to have strongly-typed view-specific data that would be inappropriate to be on your database entity, such as select lists.